# How to install Jupiter on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, jupiter

I am currently running 12.04 and I can't get Jupiter to install on my computer.

These are the commands I am running to install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

This is the error I get after updating:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/jupiter/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

and finally after install jupiter, I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package jupiter
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this issue?  Or can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm trying to install in 12.04 and the commands aren't working properly is the difference.

Comment: Post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Jupiter is no longer maintained is it?

Comment: in the update error its showing `saucy` meaning your `etc/apt/sources.list` has errors. I just installed jupiter in `precise` without any issue

Comment: Post only the output of `lsb_release -sc`

Answer (score 1):

First let's remove the old added repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
```

Now add the correct version:

```
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/jupiter/ubuntu precise main " | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list

echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/jupiter/ubuntu precise main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Now update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Its time to install

```
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

Comment: don't need to remove the PPA.Just change the word saucy to precise inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-jupiter-saucy.list` file.Then update and install jupiter.

Comment: I really not sure whether its in sources.list.d or just in sources.list specially the OP didn't post the sources.list file so just to be clean I did so...

Comment: i think, ppa should be added in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory not inside `sources.list`.I already tried this and it worked.

Comment: Yes now It's so but still some PPAs are added to the sources.list just working on the old criteria and i already installed juipter before and i know it's under sources.list.d but as i told you just to be clean

Comment: But both will works.

Comment: Yes sure both will do